# TypeScript uility type to convert all key types into arrays of that key type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface (type) defined as

```
 interface User {
     name: string,
     id: string,
     age: number,
     town: string
 }
```

I now have a function which will search for Users which match a particular field or fields. I **don't** want to have to manually declare another type UserFilter, e.g.:

```
 interface UserFilter {
     name: string[],
     id: string[],
     age: number[],
     town: string[]
 }
```

To be able to do

```
function findUsers(filter: Partial<UserFilter>) {
   if (filter.id) {
    mySQLQueryBuilder.whereIn('id', filter.id)
   }
   ...
}
```

Basically in User every key was a scalar and in UserFilter it is now an array of the same type.

I feel that having to create a separate type (UserFilter), which is so similar to User, is wasteful and more surface area for bugs/maintaince.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use TypeScript's (utility?) types to basically convert the `User` type's fields into arrays of the same type (I call this `ConvertAllKeysToArrays`)

```
function findUsers(filter: Partial<ConvertAllKeysToArrays<User>>) {
   if (filter.id) {
    mySQLQueryBuilder.whereIn('id', filter.id)
   }
   ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no existing utility type for this, but we can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to make our own.

```
type MapToArrays<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K][]
}

type UserFilter = MapToArrays<User>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRRIcAthAFzLphSgDmANAcUcACbW30jOts4DKshABXMgCNoLQmzAB7AO4hudRgQC+BAmACeABxQBZOAYAqCgIJQocPegA85gHzIAvDgFEA2gGlkUGQAawg9BRhkcwBdanN-aJ9orR18fSM0TCgAMWAAG0goD2RTC2tbeycMaBcgA)

Comment: seem to have done the trick. good stuff. quite straight forward now you've shown me the answer